# ios datepicker crashes randomly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, datepicker

I have a `UIDatepicker` and it crashes randomly in iOS7. At the simulator, the `UIDatepicker` works perfectly but on the real device always crash. The error is `EXC_BAD_ADRESS` but the Xcode doesn't give me more information.

Please help me!

My code is:

**VistaRuedaViewController.h**

```
@interface VistaRuedaViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
{

    NSString *fecha;
    Utilidades *util;
    BOOL conexion;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAviso;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabbar;

-(IBAction)SelectSend:(id)sender;

@end
```

**VistaRuedaViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date]; 
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    ...
}

    -(IBAction)SelectSend:(id)sender{
        UIDatePicker *dp = (UIDatePicker *) sender;

        //[table reloadData];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        fecha =[formatter stringFromDate:dp.date];
        NSLog(@"FECHA DATAPICKER: %@", dp.date);

        NSString *idioma;
        NSString *currentL = [Global sharedMySingleton].test;
        if([currentL isEqualToString:@"ca-ES"]){
            idioma = @"ca";
        }
        else
        {
            idioma = currentL;
        }
        button.enabled = NO;
        NSString *PlaningURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/PlaningHorario", NSLocalizedString(@"protocolo", @""), NSLocalizedString(@"servidor", @"")];

        util = [[Utilidades alloc]init];
        conexion = [util testInternetConnection];

        if (conexion) {
            Planing_pasarela *cargaPlaning = [[Planing_pasarela alloc] init];
            [cargaPlaning NSURLConnectionFunction:PlaningURLString:fecha:fecha:idioma];

            int ret =[cargaPlaning comprobarFlag];

            button.enabled = YES;

            if (ret==1) {
                [table reloadData];
                NSLog(@"DATAPICKER: %@", fecha);
            }else{
            // Usuario y token incorrectos

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"logoutAlert", @"") message:AMLocalizedString(@"logout", @"") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                alert.tag = 1;
                [alert show];
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you for advance.

Comment: At which row `bad access`?

Comment: I don't know the row, the Xcode only shows me this: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa00000004)

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. That may help you show the exact line where the crash happens.

Comment: @kova, set breakpoint in  `-(IBAction)SelectSend:(id)sender` and move inside it row by row.

Comment: you should simplify that method, for example, presenting UIAlert view before dismissing datepicker could cause problem. Start from printing selected option, so go ahead

Comment: Ok, the problem occurs when the SelectedSend function ends. But it doesn't give me any information.

Comment: The selected option is ok, the self.datePicker.date is ok. Now I'm not using the alert, I think the alert isn't the problem...

Comment: It's possible that my problem is an iOS bug? I tried all, and I can't fix it...

Answer (score 0):

1. `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;`
   Why it's `strong` when other oultest is `retain`. You are using ARC or what?
   If you use ARC, than all oultets shold be `strong`, if not then `retain`.
2. And if you use outlet, you don't need allocate it: `datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];`
3. Use everywhere `seld.datePicker` instead `datePicker`.
4. You don't need `UIDatePicker *datePicker;` inside `@interface VistaRuedaViewController ...{ }`
5. If App is non-ARC, then you need release `formatter` and `util`

Comment: Now the error is diferent: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ( code= EXC_ARM_UNDEFINED, subcode=0xffffffc)

Comment: I release datePicker inside {} and util (the problem is still happening), but why I need release formatter?

Comment: @kova, you create it ever time in `SelectSend`, so you need to release it.

Comment: My App is ARC, so I don't need release formatter. The problem is still happening... :(